# Terracotta BigMemory shared data is not consistent

Tags: java, shared-memory, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

I thought terracotta bigmemory would easily solve data consistency issues but it requires several parameters/properties both in ehcache.xml and in source code as I read on its documentation.

my ehcache.xml is:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         name="config">

  <cache name="bigMemory"
         maxBytesLocalHeap="128M"
         copyOnRead="true"
         copyOnWrite="true"
         eternal="true">

    <terracotta consistency="strong" />
  </cache>

  <terracottaConfig url="localhost:9510" rejoin="false"/>

</ehcache>
```

And the code snippet that reads and increments the existing value on shared data is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            transactionController.begin();
            bigMemoryChip.put(new Element(uid, ((Long) bigMemoryChip.get(uid).getObjectValue())+1));
            transactionController.commit();
        }
```

What I did is executing the code twice and observe how it handles consistency and normally what I expected is having the final value 2000 more than the initial value.

Although I tried about 15 times, only once it was 2000 more than the initial value, but the all of others were about 1500-1700 more than the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your `transactionController` is, but unless it is a clustered data structure providing exclusion, the operations you are performing are *not atomic* and thus you see the race between the `put` and `get`.

That is there could be a `put` happening on the other node between the `get` and `put` on this node, which would end up *hiding* increments.

As you are using *strong consistency*, the test will pass if you change the `put` in a conditional `replace`.

Comment: transactionController belongs to the cache object. And as far as the documentation tolds; begin and commit methods will guarantee the atomicity.  and 'yes', consistency is strong. (see .xml above) @louis_jacomet

Comment: Ok, can you indicate how you get it? And it probably means you are trying to use local transactions without configuring them. So not surprised it does not work as expected.